# Why does the first parameter of the function LdrRegisterDllNotification have to be zero?

Tags: windows, dll, ntdll

As stated in the Microsoft docs, the parameter `Flags` of the [`LdrRegisterDllNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devnotes/ldrregisterdllnotification) must be zero, but no further explanation is provided. What's the purpose of defining this parameter at all if the only accepted value is zero? What happens if a non-zero value is passed instead?

Comment: All nonzero values are reserved. If you pass a nonzero value, then it may stop working in a future version of Windows because that nonzero value will have some new meaning.

Comment: @RaymondChen you may as well post the comment as answer

Comment: @Wander3r It's a dup of all the other "Parameter is documented as 'reserved, must be zero', so why have it?" questions. Reserved must be zero means reserved, must be zero

Answer (score 1):

Parameters where the documentation tells you to pass zero has two possible reasons:

1. The parameter is unused in all existing Windows versions but might be used for something in the future. The developer might have envisioned extra features but they did not have time to implement them etc.
2. The parameter is used to pass undocumented information/flags that triggers some private functionality inside the function. Windows 95 for example supports undocumented flags in its `*Alloc` functions that causes them to allocate shared memory visible to all processes.

Either way, the best practice is to just follow the documentation and pass zero.